# Meaning of $ in a string?

Tags: string, svn, character

I came along this

```
__date__ = "$Date: 2011/06$"
```

and found this [in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings)

> - $$ is an escape; it is replaced with a single $.
> - `$identifier` names a substitution placeholder matching a mapping key of `"identifier"`. By default, `"identifier"` must spell a Python identifier. The first non-identifier character after the $ character terminates this placeholder specification.
> - `${identifier}` is equivalent to $identifier. It is required when valid `identifier` characters follow the placeholder but are not part of the placeholder, such as `"${noun}ification"`.

but I don't understand it.

Could someone explain in plain english what's the `$` for and give some examples preferably?

Comment: Those docs apply to the `string.Templae` class. Are you using the `string.Templae` class?

Comment: @rob nope, I'm not. Is there any general meaning of `$` (in strings)? If you could provide a link, that'd be fine..

Comment: I suspect that what you're seeing there is something like the keyword expansion feature of a source management system like CVS -- see here: http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.12.13/cvs_12.html

Comment: The `$` character has no special meaning to Python in a string. It may have meaning to the code that *uses* that string, though. What code is using that string?

Comment: @kindall Can't find the source right now. It's of an example file I adopted. I guess source management is a good hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To Python, those dollar signs mean nothing at all. Just like the `'D'` or `'a'` that follow, the dollar sign is merely a character in a string.

To your source-code control system, the dollar signs indicate a substitution command. When you check out a new copy of your source code, that string is replaced with the timestamp of the last committed change to the file.

Reference:

- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html
- http://www.badgertronics.com/writings/cvs/keywords.html

Comment: If some CVS expert reads this, feel free to edit an actual official reference into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This has been used in the context of string replace. For ex, if you have scenario with a variable which takes different value in same string, you can use this as follows:

```
import string
mytext = "$dog is an animal"
replaceDogtoCat = {"dog":"cat"}
mytemplate = string.Template(mytext)
print mytemplate.substitute(replaceDogtoCat) #output: cat is an animal
replaceDogtoGoat = {"dog":"goat"}
print mytemplate.substitute(replaceDogtoGoat) #output: goat is an animal
```

$dog is a variable which would get replaced when substitute gets executed